# XSD Validation error when Importing element from another XSD

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

I have been trying to learn XSD and was trying some sample Project in eclipse. So I have created two xsd's by name HospitalSchema.xsd and PatientSchema.xsd. I am trying to refer a Complex Type element from HospitalSchema.xsd into PatientSchema.xsd by importing the HospitalSchema.xsd. Here are the xsd's

HospitalSchema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/HospitalSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/HospitalSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<element name="Hospital">
    <complexType>
        <all>
            <element name="name" type="string"/>
            <element name="Address" type="string"/>
        </all>
    </complexType>  
</element>
```

PatientSchema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/PatientSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/PatientSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:hoschema="http://www.example.org/HospitalSchema">

<import namespace="http://www.example.org/HospitalSchema" schemaLocation="HospitalSchema.xsd"/>

<element name="patient" type="tns:patientType" />

<complexType name="patientType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="id" type="tns:ID" />
        <element name="name" type="tns:string15Chars" />
        <element name="dob" type="date" />
        <element name="gender" type="tns:Gender" />
        <element name="payBy" type="tns:Payment"/>
        <element name="hospitalName" type="hoschema:Hospital" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<simpleType name="ID">
    <restriction base="int">
        <pattern value="[0-9]*"></pattern>  
    </restriction>
</simpleType>

<simpleType name="string15Chars">
    <restriction base="string">
        <maxLength value="15"></maxLength>
    </restriction>  
</simpleType>

<simpleType name="Gender">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="M"></enumeration>
        <enumeration value="F"></enumeration>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>

<complexType name="Payment">
    <choice>
        <element name="cash" type="int"/>
        <element name="insurance" type="tns:Insurance"/>
    </choice>   
</complexType>

<complexType name="Insurance">
    <all>
        <element name="provider" type="string"/>
        <element name="limit" type="int"/>
    </all>
</complexType>
```

type="hoschema:Hospital" is the complexType I am trying to import from another schema. But Eclipse has been throwing error saying

`src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'hoschema:Hospital' to a(n) 'type definition' component.    PatientSchema.xsd   /Patient    line 17 XML Schema Problem`

Both the XSD's are in the same Eclipse Project. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hoschema:Hospital` is an element declaration, not a type.

I suspect you want to replace

```
<element name="hospitalName" type="hoschema:Hospital" />
```

by

```
<element ref="hoschema:Hospital" />
```

Comment: Thanks. type was the issue. Created a New Complex Type  "HospitalType" in HospitalSchema.xsd and it worked

Answer (score -1):

Here are 2 things I noticed (I'm not an expert on XSDs...).

You could replace

```
<import namespace="http://www.example.org/HospitalSchema" schemaLocation="HospitalSchema.xsd"/>
```

by

```
<include schemaLocation="HospitalSchema.xsd"/>
```

Also I think your *targetNamespace* should be the same in both XSD files.

After making those changes I now get an error stating that tns:Insurance is not defined, so I guess that was your next task.

Comment: Thanks for looking into. I am still getting the same error if I replace an import with include.

Comment: No, this advice is incorrect. The two schema documents have different target namespace, so you need import rather than include.